# How to bind two field values to a single text box

Tags: html, angularjs

I am working on angularJS and Html,

from my angularJs side I am getting two fields they are

```
name.firstname, name.lastname,
```

So in my html i will be able to display it like this

```
<div>{{name.firstname}}-{{ name.lastname}}</div>
```

but i want to display these two values in a single text box separated by ","

I tried as given below but it is not working

```
<div><input type ='text' ng-model ="name.firstname" , "name.firstname"/></div>
```

please suggest me how to do this in a simple way without using any directives

Comment: in js `$scope.name.fullName=name.firstName+","+name.lastName;` and in html `<input type ='text' ng-model ='name.fullName'/>`

Comment: and what should happen if user types something in the textbox? Should it update some variable?

Comment: `ng-model` is designed to bind JavaScript variables to input boxes.  If you changed what is typed in the input box, would you expect it to update the `firstname` or the `lastname`, or somehow intelligently know that the `,` means there are 2 values? Before trying to figure out how to bind 2 variables to a single textbox, let's figure out why you *want* to do something like that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can assign model to your input and assign it the sum of fname and lname:-)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div>
    <input type ='text' ng-model ='name'"/>
    </div>
</div>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.fname = 'raciit';
    $scope.lname = 'gulati';
    $scope.name=$scope.fname+$scope.lname;

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyccx50p/)

Comment: this does work, but it still doesn't explain why they want a textbox in the first place; in this case, typing in the textbox won't change anything at all in the model.